# cPanel Deployment: my app.js is exposed for everyone to see

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, cpanel

I've developed a tiny app in a hosted server via cPanel, by using node js with express and mysql.
so when the app is running via node or forever, it is accessible only when I add the port number in the url. but when the url is without the port, it goes to an Index of the files in the folder of the subdomain. and everyone can view the app.js file including the password to mysql and user name etc...

I thought js files are not accessible or viewable to the client??

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create ".htaccess" file in the root of your project with following content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXX/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXX/$1 [P,L]
```

Where the "XXXX" is the port, that you're using.

Comment: thank you. is that standard protocol? i read that if i put index.html in my subdomain it will also won't show "Index of" files. but as I've create a dynamic webpage, I'm not routing through index.html

Comment: I forgot to mention this is meant for subdomain. so, i found a code that worked for subdomains in .htaccess , so instead of giving me folder with file names that the client can view, it gives 500 internal error.